# Play video from any folder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uikit

i know this has been a part of many topics, but i want to play a downloaded movie elsewhere than in resource (particularly in the application support folder)

i use :

```
    NSString * html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<video src=\"%@.%@\">Alt Text</video>", self.file.uid, self.file.extension];
    NSURL * base = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[DocumentsModel pathToStorageDirectory]];

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 412.0)];

    [self.webView setOpaque:NO];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:base];
```

The value of HTML is

```
    <video src="9812.mp4">Alt Text</video>
```

The value of base is

```
    <CFURL 0x7bd9c00 [0x2478b38]>{type = 15, string = file://localhost/Users/peterpaulis/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/C0831A31-048A-4402-9638-696CC085C17B/Library/Application%20Support/tproj/Storage/, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}
```

- note that the file exists at

  file://localhost/Users/peterpaulis/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/C0831A31-048A-4402-9638-696CC085C17B/Library/Application%20Support/tproj/Storage/9812.mp4

and is ok

but no playback is done

i also tryied

```
<video id="player" width="480" height="320" src"..." webkit-playsinline>

self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

but the result is the same, the video doesn't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. include the MediaPlayer Framework
2. must use the video tag, with webkit-playsinline
3. self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
4. typo with src"..." -> src="..."